# How to create tables in windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do you create a table in winforms where individual cells can look like this:
[image]

I have been using a tablelayoutpanel, but it only lets you but one control per cell.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can do this - you might need to create your own control but it is possible. A work around would be to have a SplitContainer control and 3 Panels

Comment: Look into `.SpansRows` and `.SpansColumns` properties for the control inside a cell.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to emulate this is to use nested tablelayoutpanels.

To get your desired output in the example:

```
TableLayout1: 1 Row, 2 Columns
TableLayout2 goes within column2 of TableLayout1: 3 Rows, 1 Column
```

Answer (score 2):

There is ALWAYS a way to get it to work. It may not be obvious from the WinForms designer, but it is not too hard.

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  partial class Form_1:Form 
  {

    public Form_1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing && (components != null))
      {
        components.Dispose();
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
      this.panel4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
      this.panel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
      this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
      this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
      this.SuspendLayout();
      // 
      // tableLayoutPanel1
      // 
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 25F));
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 75F));
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel4, 3, 0);
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel3, 2, 0);
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2, 1, 0);
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.panel1, 0, 0);
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(this.panel1, 3);//This line is the key!!!!!
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3;
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 33.33333F));
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(527, 372);
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0;
      // 
      // panel4
      // 
      this.panel4.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      this.panel4.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.panel4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 251);
      this.panel4.Name = "panel4";
      this.panel4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(390, 118);
      this.panel4.TabIndex = 4;
      // 
      // panel3
      // 
      this.panel3.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      this.panel3.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.panel3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 127);
      this.panel3.Name = "panel3";
      this.panel3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(390, 118);
      this.panel3.TabIndex = 3;
      // 
      // panel2
      // 
      this.panel2.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      this.panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 3);
      this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
      this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(390, 118);
      this.panel2.TabIndex = 2;
      // 
      // panel1
      // 
      this.panel1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
      this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
      this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
      this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
      this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(125, 366);
      this.panel1.TabIndex = 1;
      // 
      // Form1
      // 
      this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
      this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
      this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(527, 372);
      this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
      this.Name = "Form1";
      this.Text = "Form1";
      this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
      this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel4;
  }
}
```

The key to get this to work is this line:

```
this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetRowSpan(this.panel1, 3);//This line is the key!!!!!
```